# Generate entites not work for OneToMany relation in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relation

I have a entity :

> ```
> /**
>  * @ORM\Entity
>  * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
>  */
> class Organization
> {
>
>
>     /*
>      *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Link" , mappedBy="organization")
>      */
>     private $links;
>
>
>     /**
>      * Get id
>      *
>      * @return integer 
>      */
>     public function getId()
>     {
>         return $this->id;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Set title
>      *
>      * @param string $title
>      * @return Organization
>      */
>     public function setTitle($title)
>     {
>         $this->title = $title;
>
>         return $this;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Get title
>      *
>      * @return string 
>      */
>     public function getTitle()
>     {
>         return $this->title;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Set site
>      *
>      * @param string $site
>      * @return Organization
>      */
>     public function setSite($site)
>     {
>         $this->site = $site;
>
>         return $this;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Get site
>      *
>      * @return string 
>      */
>     public function getSite()
>     {
>         return $this->site;
>     }
>
>
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->links = new ArrayCollection();
>     }
>     }
> ```

when run command :

```
php console doctrine:generate:entities News/VillageNewsBundle/Entity/Organization
```

when i run this command all the getter and setter 
will generated but getter and setter for relation not add to my entity?!

Comment: yes because its mapped by Link

Comment: @johnSmith your answer not true please read this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your *OneToMany* annotation is wrong.

You must use the correct doc synthax, which is:

```
/**
 * [...]
 */
```

Here, it misses one '*' before your OneToMany annotation. Add it and it will work. :-)